# Как правильно нормализовать БД?

Tags: sql

Суть задания: для производственной практики нужно разработать БД для комиссионного магазина, он хранит разные компьютерные компоненты: видеокарту, процессор и т.д. Не подумав о том, как будут реализованы связи между таблицами, я стал создавать таблицы с разными полями для определенной товарной позиции, т.к. мне показалось глупым все товары пихать в одну таблицу, там куча нюансов. Теперь мне кажется глупым то, что решил делать несколько таблиц под каждую товарную позицию, т.к. теперь не могу сообразить логически как реализовывать добавление товаров в корзину.

Вот так в черновом варианте выглядят связи. Буду в таблицы "видеокарта", "блок питания" и т.д. добавлять дополнительные поля для привязки подкатегории.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как корзину реализовывать? Так же добавлять вторичный ключ "Корзина" к товарным позициям в виде еще одной строки? В интернете делают иначе, там одна таблица "Товары", с которой удобно работать, но а в моем случае что делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Неужели все переделывать из-за глупости...

Comment: Все можно не переделывать, а сделать небольшой рефакторинг текущей базы. Правильное выделение сущностей на этапе проектирования очень важно, вы работаете в первую очередь с товарами в приложении. Какие они, это уже вторичный признак товара, а не основной. Поэтому вы можете выделить отдельную таблицу (Product), куда соберете общие характеристики, такие как ID, Код, Имя, Описание, Цена, Категория, Подкатегория. В текущих таблицах добавить внешний ключ Product_ID и просто ссылаться на основную таблицу. По факту у вас просто общие характеристики переедут в общую таблицу.

Comment: ... а не-общие разумнее хранить в EAV.